# How to install Automapper for .net 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, automapper, nuget

I would like to use Automapper with .net 3.5.

I have found a branch on Git hub, thanks to [this post](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/08/17/automapper-upgraded-to-net-4-and-vs-2010/) by the creator Jimmy Bogard:

...but I can't figure out how to install it.

The .net 4 version is installed using [nuget](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/installing-nuget)

Anyone know how I install the .net 3.5 version?

Do I just build it myself, and use it as my own project?

If so how do I build it? Do I need to create a NuGet package?

Comment: You may experience nuget's failure to install AutoMapper with a 3.5-based project with the error message "Install-Package : Could not install package 'AutoMapper 2.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that tar
gets '.NETFramework,Version=v3.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that fram
ework. For more information, contact the package author."

Answer (score 21, accepted):

https://github.com/downloads/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.dll

This .dll is version 1.1 which according to the site is the last .net 3.5 version. Just reference it in your project and it should work.

Answer (score 8):

No need to build the source yourself. AutoMapper 1.1 is available on NuGet at http://nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/1.1.0.118

PM Console command is 
PM> Install-Package AutoMapper -Version 1.1.0.118

Answer (score 5):

> **Do I just build it myself, and use it as my own project?**

Yes, although you don't need to include the AutoMapper project in your solution;

> **If so how do I build it? Do I need to create a NuGet package?**

NuGet package not required.

You need to download the source for AutoMapper for .net3.5 from [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/zipball/NET35)

Once downloaded, you can open the `sln` file under the `src` folder and build the AutoMapper project (just that project will do)

You can then copy the dll produced (i.e., found at `src\AutoMapper\bin\Debug`) to your shared lib folder and reference that.